# Force Token Refresh in Xamarin Forms Android, Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to force a token refresh with Firebase. Sometimes it works and deleting the FirebaseInstanceId does trigger the OnTokenRefresh() but most of the times it doesn't and i don't understand why. I have to run the program a lot of times for the OnTokenRefresh to be triggered. When I put a break point on FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstnaceId() and then click Continue from the Debugger once that line is hit, the OnTokenRefresh() is not called.Google Play services availability method does return true, I checked. Any help please? Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            //added for spalsh
            //base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            //base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            //add for using maps
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

            //add for using with Azure
            CurrentPlatform.Init();

            //add for using local database
            string dbName = "sa_db.sqlite";
            string dbFolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string dbFullPath = Path.Combine(dbFolderPath, dbName);

            //loadApplcation with db path ---> add dbFullPath as param
            LoadApplication(new App());

            // check if google play services are available
            var availability = IsPlayServiceAvailable();

#if DEBUG
            // Force the refresh of the token. If we deploy the app, no new token will be sent out
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //string currentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

                //This may not be executed on the main thread
                FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId();             
                Console.WriteLine("Forced token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
            });
#endif
        }
```

In debug mode this should be triggered (but seems to only trigger on a random basis):

```
// should be triggered when InstanceId is deleted
 [Service]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
        public class MyFirebaseIIDService: FirebaseInstanceIdService
        {
            public override void OnTokenRefresh()
            {
                //base.OnTokenRefresh();

                var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
                // Token received message
                Console.WriteLine ($"Token received: {refreshedToken} ");

                SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
            }

    // check if GoogPlay Serice is available
    public  bool IsPlayServiceAvailable()
            {
                int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

                if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
                {
                    if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                    {
                        // give the user a change to fix the issue
                        // error message
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // play services not supported message

                        Finish();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // services are available message               
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a CLEAN and REBUILD in Visual Studio seems to have solved the problem.